# LINQ TO SQL Compare nullable date time in where condition

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ TO SQL.
Following is the code I am using to fetch data from Database.

```
contractMaintenances = mdbDataContext.ContractMaintenances
                         .Where(c => c.ContractID == contractId
                             && c.ChargeFrequencyID == periodFrequencyId
                             && c.FirstPeriodStartDate == (firstPeriodStartDate == null ? null : firstPeriodStartDate)
                             && c.FinalRenewalEndDate == (finalBillingPeriodEndDate.HasValue ? finalBillingPeriodEndDate : (DateTime?)null)
                             && c.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
```

Here above FinalRenewalEndDate is nullable in database, So if finalBillingPeriodEndDate has value then use that value otherwise null.

but if is not working I have checked in SQL profiler below is the profiler SQL.

```
WHERE ([t0].[ContractID] = @p0) 
    AND ([t0].[ChargeFrequencyID] = @p1) 
    AND ([t0].[FirstPeriodStartDate] = @p2) 
    AND ([t0].[FinalRenewalEndDate] = @p3) 
    AND (NOT ([t0].[IsDeleted] = 1))',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 datetime,@p3 datetime',@p0=16422,@p1=4,@p2='2012-05-01 00:00:00',@p3=NULL
```

but if I compare null value directly with field then it is working fine.

```
&& c.FinalRenewalEndDate == null
```

if I pass null as directly then it will generate proper output me. It will not pass p3 parameter in SQL Profiler.

```
WHERE ([t0].[ContractID] = @p0) 
    AND ([t0].[ChargeFrequencyID] = @p1) 
    AND ([t0].[FirstPeriodStartDate] = @p2) 
    AND ([t0].[FinalRenewalEndDate] IS NULL) 
    AND (NOT ([t0].[IsDeleted] = 1))',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 datetime',@p0=16422,@p1=4,@p2='2012-05-01 00:00:00'
```

What will be the fix. I have 3 optional date parameter. If I wan't find any solution then I have to write multiple if condition to check for null parameter and I dont want to write those conditions.

Comment: you can directly write object.Equals(c.FinalRenewalEndDate,finalBillingPeriodEndDate)

Comment: try move field into ternary operator like `(finalBillingPeriodEndDate.HasValue ? (c.FinalRenewalEndDate ==  finalBillingPeriodEndDate) : (c.FinalRenewalEndDate == null))`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use object.Equals instead of the equality operator:

```
object.Equals(c.FinalRenewalEndDate, finalBillingPeriodEndDate.HasValue ? finalBillingPeriodEndDate : (DateTime?)null)
```

Comment: you can directly write object.Equals(c.FinalRenewalEndDate,finalBillingPeriodEndDate)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try writing your condition without `?:` operator.

```
 && c.FinalRenewalEndDate == finalBillingPeriodEndDate
```